# Replace for Headers and Header

Tags: java, android, xml, soap, header

I searched for an object that can replace Headers,Header, WSBindingProvider cause
those objects doesn't recognize by Android. 
Just for explaining myself, I need this for doing some
soap format and use Element object.
Thanks for anyone who can help or know something!

the libararies:

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Header;
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, 
I post it for people who might need it:

download the jar and use it in the project, it's has most of the
soap api object:
    http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxwsrt217jar.htm